# Chakra UI Image component not recognizing image path

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I'm currently learning how to use ChakraUI

When trying to load local images using
`import { Box, Heading, Text, Image } from "@chakra-ui/react";` they don't display at all, just the alt text as if their paths where not properly typed, I also tried to type the image source directly into the component.

The `nextjs/image` component works properly with **the exact same `src` path** and I haven't got any information on this particular error, I have also tried the `@chakra-ui/image` component and the  `import { Img } from "@chakra-ui/react";` as Im working using **Nextjs** too, neither of those chakra options have worked for me.

```
import React from "react";
import { Box, Heading, Text, Image } from "@chakra-ui/react";
// import Image from "next/image"; //The nextjs image component does works! 
import source from "../images/logo.svg";
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Box bg="brand.900" w="100%" p={4} color="white">
      <Box>
        <Image src={source} alt="s" w={100} h={100} borderRadius="full" />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

On the ChakraUI documentation its never used a local path as an example, but i supposed it wouldn't be a problem

Comment: Try moving your `images` folder to the `public` folder and then reference the image by its path directly `<Image src="/images/logo.svg" ... />`.

Comment: Doing that got me a 'Javascript Memory heap' error, as described here
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7929

Comment: It seems to be some error regarding memory heap when adding images on the `/public` folder.

Answer (score 7):

The only solution that I found is to put your images directly inside the public folder. And then import the Image component from charkra-ui/react

[image]

```
import {Image} from '@chakra-ui/react'

const ImageComponent = () => {
  return {
     <Image src="/hero.jpg" alt="hero-image"/>
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you should try to import image from directory and name this import. Then write name of import in <Image src='{nameOfImport} />.

Example :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Image } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import nameOfImport from './nameOfPhoto.png'

const ImageBackground = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Image src={nameOfImport}  alt='Background image' />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default ImageBackground;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, but in my case, I didn't use import. After using import as you did above, it worked fine.

Now since you are using Next.js, I suggest you import and use the Chakra `Img` component from `@chakra-ui/react` and use that instead. This tip is from the [Chakra UI author](https://github.com/segunadebayo) on this [thread](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/2815#issuecomment-747611286)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the other alternative also could be, just saving the images on the public folder